# how to run the example of uima-text-segmenter?

Tags: uima, text-segmentation

I want to call the API of uima-text-segmenter  https://code.google.com/p/uima-text-segmenter/source/browse/trunk/INSTALL?r=22 to run an example.
But I don`t know how to call the API...
the readme said,

```
With the DocumentAnalyzer, run the following descriptor
`desc/textSegmenter/wst-snowball-C99-JTextTilingAAE.xml` by taking the 
uima-examples data as input.
```

Could anyone give me some code which could be run directly in main func for example?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Long answer:

The link describes how you would set up the application from within the Eclipse UIMA environment. This sort of set-up is typically targeted at subject matter specialists with little or no coding experience. It allows them to work (relatively fast) with UIMA in a declarative way: all data structures and analysis engines (computing blocks within UIMA) are declared in xml (with a GUI on top of it), after which the framework takes care of the rest. In this scenario, you would typically run a UIMA pipeline using a run configuration from within Eclipse (or the included UIMA pipeline runner application). Luckily, UIMA allows you to do exactly the same from code, but I would recommend using UIMAFit (http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#d5e137) for this purpose instead of of UIMA, as it bundles lots of useful things and coding shortcuts.

Short answer:

Using UIMAFit, you can call Factory methods that create CollectionReader (read input), AnalysisEngine (process input) and Consumer objects (write/do other stuff) from (third-party provided) XML files. Use these methods to construct your pipeline and the SimplePipeline class to run it. To extract the data you need, you would manipulate the CAS object (containing your data) in a Consumer object, possibly with a callback. You could also do this in a Analysis Engine object. I recommend using DKPro's FeaturePathFactory (https://code.google.com/p/dkpro-core-asl/source/browse/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core-asl/trunk/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.api.featurepath-asl/src/main/java/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/api/featurepath/FeaturePathFactory.java?spec=svn1811&r=1811) to quickly access the feature you are after.

Code examples:

http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/tools.uimafit.book.html#d5e137 contains examples, but they all go in the opposite direction (class objects are used in the factory methods, instead of XML files - XML is generated from these classes). Take a look at the UIMAFit API to find the method you need, AnalysisEngineDescription from XML for example: http://uima.apache.org/d/uimafit-current/api/org/apache/uima/fit/factory/AnalysisEngineFactory.html#createEngineDescriptionFromPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-